# Good OO practice + Should we implement complicated logic in subclasses for sake of OO?

Tags: java, oop

I have an Employee classified into two ( domestic and international ).
I have another class Refund, which is used to refund employees.
I have a class called Bank account used by Refund class to Refund.

Now my immediate design looks like this:

Employee interface, with 2 sub-types domestic and international.

Refund class takes in Bank in constructor.

A rough pseudocode of Refund class

```
Class Refund

    Refund( bank account )

   Public class Refund( employee ) {

         If (employee is domestic) {
             Pay to bank
             Account for taxes
        } else {
           do currency conversion
           Pay to bank 
           Call some 3rd party to do taxation
       }
    }
}
```

Now here is my question:

1. How can I replace Refund class with object oriented design, which is extensible and I don’t need to use if-else ?
2. Immediate option is to shift refund functionality into Employee class and individual subtypes can then do their own logic for refund. BUT-  does it make sense to complicate employee class with Refund logic ( which deservers its own modular class given it’s complex functions ) ?

Comment: Template pattern allow you to implement an algorithm and it let to the subclases to do custom work.  Here you could have a `RefundForDomestic` class and a `RefundForInternational`, and a `Refund` class that is its parent.  Then, Employee has a property of type `Refund`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I briefly read your question, I think double dispatch is what you seek.
See e. g. https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor/java/2

Comment: The first part of tutorial will be better https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor/java/1

Answer (score 1):

To keep the OO design and make it extensible, without shifting the functionality to the Employee class, perhaps you just add attributes to the employee class such as employee type (domestic / international) as well as a refund type, which you could then use the now extendable Refund class to make particular types of refunds?

Answer (score 1):

Employee -> Account[] with Type, currencies -> Entries[]

Employee -> Account[] with currencies-> Entries[] with type

You can use each Account for type (refund) and currencies, or better a Account only for each currencies and the Entry with type (Refund)

The rest should be done by a service!